# Разность maxRange акселлерометра и его истинных показаний

Tags: java, android, android-studio

в Android Studio

```
public void SensorData()
{

SensorManager sensorManager=
(SensorManager)currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    Sensor defaultacc = 
    sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    maxrange = defaultacc.getMaximumRange();
}
```

maxrange показывает что сенсор может мерить до 39 м.с^2
Однако, код ниже

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{

    if(event.sensor.getType()== Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        float[] values= event.values;

        ax= values[0]; //Вот эти значения осей не доходят даже до 20 м/c^2
        ay= values[1];
        az= values[2];

}
```

Показывает максимальные результаты в 2 раза меньше - не более 19 с копейками м/c^2

В чем дело? Есть ли возможность поднять порог до 39 м\с^2, как написано в инфо о сенсоре? Тестировал на нескольких телефонах.

Comment: может недостаточно сильно трясли телефон?

Comment: @rjhdby
Достаточно. Записывалось именно максимальное значение, а если что то больше него - оно становилось максимальным.
Значение никогда не поднималось выше 19 с небольшим, хотя и легко достигало этих цифр - это же всего 2 ускорения свободного падения. Рукой можно натрясти и на 40 и на 50 м\с^2.

Comment: две теории есть:
1) Все врут (с). В смысле производители акселеромтров.
2) 2*19... ~ 39...  Тобишь это не максимальное ускорение, а диапазон ускорений. От -19 до +19

Answer (score 0):

На многих телефонах некоторые сенсоры показывают неверные максимальные значения.

Как решить?

1) Попросить пользователя очень сильно потрясти телефон и замерить(т.е. своеобразная калибровка).

2) Через native снимать данные напрямую. Тут много сложностей разные производители сенсоров.

Вобщем первоочередная задача выяснить кто именно дает неправильные данные.
Может даже сам производитель немного урезать.